# Appending to CSV file, can I use seek to determine if header should be written? Is there a better way?

Tags: ruby, performance, csv, file, io

I have to generate some CSV files and write them to disk. Unfortunately, I only get one line of the file at a time.
I have to do lots of writes per second so I want my program to be as efficient as possible (minimize disk operations)

I currently have the following ruby code to build the csv:

```rb
def add_line(doc)
    File.open("myfile.csv", "a") do |f|
        f.seek(0, IO::SEEK_END)                            # Move cursor to end of file (is this costly?)
        f.write(doc.keys.join(",") + "\n") if f.pos() == 0 # Write header if cursor position is 0
        f.write(doc.values.join(",") + "\n")               # Write CSV line
    end
end

# Write line to file
add_line({
    key1: "value1",
    key2: "value2",
    key3: "value3"
})
```

**What is the most efficient way to determine if the header should be written?**
I could check the size of the file first and write the header if it is 0.
Is using `seek` more efficient?
Is there a better way to accomplish this?

A little more background on the use case:
I am writing these CSV files to a Ceph volume (a distributed file system), and I am trying to minimize the strain on the file system as much as possible (since these writes are going to be very high volume)

I wish that ruby could indicate whether or not the file had to be created or not when opening in append mode since it would save me from having to make this additional check.

Thanks!

Comment: Can a zero-byte file exist or will you always add content (at least the header) when you create it? If the latter just check if the file exists. If it doesn't write the header and more if desired. You don't need to do any seeking; the append option `"a"` will put the write pointer at the end of the file. Any particular reason you are not using [CSV](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) methods?

Comment: Thanks @CarySwoveland. The files should never be 0 bytes -- they will either have one or more lines or be empty. 

I thought about checking if the File exists, but I am writing the files to a Ceph volume and I'm worried that doing File.exist and File.open every single time when writing lines will cause too much strain on the distributed file system.  

The only reason I'm doing f.seek is because I want to get the cursor position to determine if the file is empty. For some reason, f.tell() and f.pos() always return 0 in append mode unless seek is called first.

Comment: However I think this solution (using f.seek) is no better than using File.exists because I suspect that SEEK_END is essentially also doing an fstat under the hood.

Ideally I wish that File.open in append mode would indicate whether or not the file existed or had to be created, but I don't think there is any way to get that information without doing a separate check.

Comment: Chicking via `strace` I see that your approach (`seek` + `pos`) requires _two_ `lseek` system calls under the hood - versus a single call to `fstat` in case of `f.size`. On the other hand, unlike `IO#seek` (which returns 0) `IO#sysseek` returns the position itself, so `<write headers> if f.sysseek(0, IO::SEEK_END) == 0` will require a single `lseek` I guess (didn't check, but I'd be surprised if not)...